# Pandas: Number of passed axes does not match the number of columns to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot three columns of a pandas data frame to a 2x2 subplot layout:

```
rand=np.random.random((12,6))
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f'],data=rand)
ax=df.loc[:,'a':'c'].plot(subplots=True,layout=(2,2))
```

This gives me the desired result (with an empty plot in the lower right corner). However, if I try to add another column to all of these subplots using

```
df.loc[:,'d':'f'].plot(subplots=True,ax=ax)
```

the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: The number of passed axes must be 3, the same as the output plot
```

Is there any solution to this problem without having to rearrange the layout of the subplots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of

```
ax=df.plot(subplots=True,layout=(2,2))
```

`ax` is a 2x2 array with 4 elements. Those are the 4 axes, where the last one is invisible if `df` only contains 3 columns. When plotting again 3 columns you need to supply 3 axes, not all 4. An option is to index the `ax` array to the number of columns to use.

```
df2.plot(subplots=True,ax=ax.flatten()[:3])
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

rand=np.random.random((12,6))
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f'],data=rand)

ax=df.loc[:,'a':'c'].plot(subplots=True,layout=(2,2))
df.loc[:,'d':'f'].plot(subplots=True,ax=ax.flatten()[:3])

plt.show()
```